# Hub/Pivot App template breaks when navigated

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I using universal app model, Hub/Pivot App template. There's some bug with template.

When I navigate from **hub.html** to other html-page (created as PageControl) and go back then Hub/Pivot layout breaks! This pic clearly show you what happens: [screenshot](http://1drv.ms/1zBKzDt).

What I'm doing:
1. Create PageControl [as it is written](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx)
2. WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/somefolder/somepage.html");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing class in CSS-file of page created as PageControl.
Here's code we need to edit:

```
.fragment {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 128px 1fr;
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just change class in html- and css-file, for example, to **fragment2**, and nothing breaks when you navigation back and forward.